# SQLServer - Skip wrong rows on insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to insert data from a table into another table, the first table is a varchar and the second one is a date.

I know about the `convert` and almost every row (in the varchar table) has the correct format. But some are wrong.

I have 70000 rows and if I try to insert all of them I got the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Maybe because a month with 30 days inserted with 31 or maybe a day inserted as 0.

*What I need is a way to skip the wrong ones and insert the rest, and a way to know what rows are wrong would be super helpful too.*

Thx guys you rock,

Comment: Add a `where` clause to filter out the wrong format

Comment: Populate a temp table with clean data using Try_PARSE(), TRY_CONVERT(), your choice, then insert into your new table from the temp table.

Comment: Add the tag for the specific version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: The `where` clause only works if I know all the erros and I don't, and I thought about a new table but is there no way to do it directly?

Comment: You could surround your statement with a `Begin Try` and then catch everything. So you can also log the errors

Comment: Thx guys TRY_CONVERT() did the trick @dfundako ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx guys, I used @dfundako answer; with TRY_CONVERT I was able to see what rows are wrong (cause it returns null) and to insert the right ones the code is here

```
select 
TRY_CONVERT(datetime,
CONCAT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),db1.AnoCreaReg),'-',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),db1.MesCreaReg),'-',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),db1.DiaCreaReg))end) from Herpetologia.dbo.especimenes db1
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier just to exclude incorrect records for future research:

```
SELECT CAST(CharDateColumn as Date)
FROM ABC
WHERE IsDate(CharDateColumn) = 1;
```